# Life cycle of a backbone.js view, a few beginner questions

Tags: backbone.js

Can someone please explain, what is the life cycle of a View (controller), say, for a Row in a TODO list app?

```
App.RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
        "click #del" : "delRow"
    }
});
```

Most of the tutorials, the AppView would do this:

```
    render: function()
    {
        this.collection.each(this.renderRow, this);
        return this;
    },
    renderRow: function(row)
    {
        var rowView = new App.RowView({model:element});
        this.$('#rows').append(rowView.render().el);
    }
```

Questions:

1. does that mean `rowView` is only used once and disposed in `renderRow()`?  Or does it live on?
2. if true, when to kill the View?  is adding listener to `model.destroy` and invoke `remove()` at the view good enough?
3. If I already have the row's markup rendered from the server, would the `click #del` events still get captured and do something w/o a `rowView` created?
4. shouldn't `'click #del'` be better located in the parent view, so that jQuery can delegate and attach behavior there?
5. does that mean I have 1 rowView per row?  wouldn't that mean the _.template is being compiled on every row? any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The *reference* dies, the *View* can remain if there are other references pointing to it.
2. You *kill* the View when is not needed any more, normally when is not visible any more. If your View is *binding* any event you have to unbinding them before call `remove()`: [Pattern to manage views in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348805/pattern-to-manage-views-in-backbone)
3. An instance of `RowView` have to be instantiated for the event to be captured.
4. This depends on the behavior you are looking for, but in your example I think each View has to capture each own `click #del` event, if you declare the event in the parent View how do you know wich row to delete?
5. Normally you declare the *template* in the View definition and you assign a *compiled* version of it to `this.template` like this: `template: _.template( "hello: <%= name %>" );`.

Comment: Re (1): there will be references to that view instance through the `delegate` call that binds the event handling to the `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort Very interesting point, I was thinking in the explicitly binded events when I say "if there are other references" but I didn't think in the DOM binded events.

Comment: The hidden reference through `delegate` is the one that bites everyone and causes leaks when they don't have a per-view-instance `el`. I know this from experience (of course), you have to clean up that hidden reference through `undelegateEvents` if several views share an `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort does that mean we should call `remove()` AND `undelegateEvents()` to be safe?  Even http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ does not mention `undelegateEvents()`

Comment: I think the situation @muistooshort is talking about is when your View is using a shared `el` and then you can't call `View.remove()` but if this is not the case, calling `View.remove()` will remove all the DOM elements binded and with them all the references of them to the View.

Comment: Thx, should I also call `model.off()` after `model.destroy()`?